# Charset problems from one page to the other

Tags: php, html, database, forms, character-encoding

I'm having the following problem.

On one page with a form, user_report.php", all characters like 'ç' or 'ã' are all correctly displayed.

Now when submitting the data, anything with those characters get's displayed/transfered to the second page, "result.php", all wrong, for example: 'Restauração' get's transfered as 'RestauraÃ§Ã£o'.

Any hints?

Comment: What character set(s) do the pages use?

Comment: You can use `iconv("input-encoding", "UTF-8", $string)` to convert to unicode.

Comment: Unfortunaly I already left the office today. I'll reply tomorrow with more. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same HTML character set on all of your pages. Make sure both of your pages have:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <!-- all of your other head tags go here, after the charset is specified -->
</head>
```

The data submitted in the form will be in whatever character set is specified in the  tag. If that character set doesn't match the one used on the second page then you'll have the bug you described.

If you don't specify any character set, then the browser will try to guess and often it will guess wrong.

It doesn't strictly matter what character set you use, as long as both pages use the same one. But utf-8 is usually the best choice.

PS: there are a few other things which can cause the bug you're having, but what I've just answered is the most common solution. If it doesn't work, please post the code you are using to fetch the content from the database and send it to the browser.